# How to port USB RNDIS device driver?

Tags: c++, windows, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

Firstly: I am totally a newbie for this kind of work.

I have a [USB rndis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) device driver for some hardware only working in XP/2000/Vista. But I want to port this to CE or Linux, and vendor also says that developer should do that.

In summary, I have XP drivers and Interface/End point configurations the driver has. And I have two questions related:

1. Why do I need to write a driver to communicate the device using IP number? Does not Windows support that by default?
2. If so what do I need to know to port the driver to another OS? I used windriver, it got the configurations, but what can I do next? What else should I know about the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer to you question directly, but there is the [Synce](http://www.synce.org) project, that is
MS ActiveSync replacement for linux. It allows to communicate with Windows Mobile devices via rndis. So if you walk over site you will find the the source of [usb-rndis-lite](http://www.synce.org/moin/SynceInstallation/Source) driver for linux.

May be this can be used as some starting point for your work.

Comment: I believe that will help me getting the basics. Thanks u!